# Removing Thumbs.db file from repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

In my project, sometimes `Thumbs.db` files got included in the repositories. I've added `*.db` in the global ignore path in `Tortoise SVN`, but still it's showing red marks on `Thumbs.db` files. Is there a way I can remove all `Thumbs.db` files from repository and ignore them for future.

I am using `Tortoise SVN` on client machine and `VisualSVN` on Server.

Comment: What **exactly** did you do to ignore and unversion the `Thumbs.db`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you've added the Thumbs.db to the *Global Ignore Pattern* in **TortoiseSVN | Settings | General**? It's a bit different from the common `svn:ignore` Subversion property.

See the quote of [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-main):

> Global ignore patterns are used to prevent **unversioned files** from
>   showing up e.g. in the commit dialog. Files matching the patterns are
>   also ignored by an import.

It says that the pattern affects only **unversioned items** and applies only to the client PC. If the `thumbs.db` was already added to Subversion or even committed you should right-click the file in your working copy then choose **TortoiseSVN | Unversion and add to ignore list**.

Further reading on [Ignoring Files And Directories with TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html).

---

If the `thumbs.db` (or any other file) was already committed to Subversion repository -- it will be there forever :) E.g. even if you apply the `svn:ignore` property to ignore the `thumbs.db` it still will be in repository history (in older revisions). BTW see the related [Apache Subversion FAQ entry](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal).

Comment: There's 'no Unversion and add to ignore list' option here, but there's a delete and add to ignore list option. I chose that, and committed, and it worked fine on the client. I read that deleting the file on server would be too difficult, so I changed it on all client machines. Thanks for the help.